# Display get the next value in the tabl

Tags: java, jsp, displaytag

I need tips to get the next value in my table displayTag. Actually I am using display tag to display information on contract

`<display:table id="tabCnt" name="listCnt" defaultsort="1" defaultorder = "ascending" pagesize="8" export="true" >
<display:column property="numCnt" title="NumCnt" sortable="true" sortName="denomination" decorator="com.dev.taglib.MyDecorator" />
<display:column property="description" title="Description" />
<display:column property="duree" title="Date end cnt" sortable="true" sortName="duree"/>
</display:table>`

Now I want to give a links for each row, which redirect me to the contract. But i want in this redirection to get the property  numCnt of the current and the next row and to put it in the URL like shown below ?

`http://mysite.com/madirection.do?numCnt="cnt1"&numCnt="cnt2"></a>`

Because I have to give the user to click a link on the new page to move to the next contract.

How I can do this ? Can you help me please !

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can not have 2 params with same name in url

```
numCnt="cnt1"&numCnt="cnt2"
```

for your url query: you can either create it from server-side: you must be creating url to poulate in href attribute of link. you can modify logic for this to append next cnt here

Or on client side: you can have onlick function which will append values to your url and submit